# Which Ra'avad is on the Rif?

Tags: historical-figures, rishonim

I am aware that there is more than one author known as the Ra'avad (ראב"ד). Is the Ra'avad with glosses to the Rif and the Ma'or the same Ra'avad as the one with glosses to the Rambam?

If they are the work of the same author, did the other Rishonim have access to both? (I ask because there seems to be a contradiction between the two, and several Rishonim quote one of them and aren't bothered by the other.)

In any case, what was the full name (with father's name if possible) and time period of each one (or just him, if it's the same person)?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RABaD_(disambiguation) for "more than one author known as the Ra'avad"

Comment: Yes, same raavad as the one on the rambam, and who wrote a peirush on most of shas even though we only have bava kama, shvuos, kidushin, and avoda zara (but the meiri and shita mekubetzes quote them a lot more; the meiri quotes him as 'gedolei hamefarshim')

Comment: Nearly all works you encounter will be of Raavad III.

Comment: How come these are all comments and not answers?